# Swift2 : read a local json file encoded in UTF-8

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization

How can I read a japanese json file with the library `NSJSONSerialization` ?

I've tried with (code with Swift2) :

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myfile",ofType:"json")
let optData =  NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!)

do {
    let abc = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(optData! as NSData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    print("data read: \(abc)")
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

But Data in abc are unreadable. So my question is : how can I change the encoding of the NSData object.

By the way, if I convert the `NSData` object into `NSString`, japanese json is perfectly encoded :

```
let stringData = NSString(data: optData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON files are always in some Unicode encoding. `NSJSONSerialization` automatically handles all the valid possibilities (including UTF-8) and the fact that your `stringData` looks reasonable suggests that the encoding is not the issue.

Looking at your code, the possibilities for something going wrong are:

- The data is not valid JSON. Try pasting it into http://jsonlint.com to see if it is OK.
- The top level object in the JSON is an array, in which case the cast to `NSDictionary` will fail. Instead of the forced cast, use `if let .... as? NSDictionary` and if that fails, try casting it to an `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you. My Json is valid, and the top level object is not an array. I ll try with a NSArray

Comment: @johann Can you put the JSON in the question? Also, the console log from running it.

Comment: After "looping" the dictionary and print the content as a String,  it get readable ! thank you